# How to access checkbox value in a flow layout panel?

Tags: c#, checkbox, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to update the value of a checkbox inside a flowlayoutpanel in c#.
The checkboxes are generated for each panel that is created and are named "selected1".

To try and access a specific checkbox in code I'm using

```
flowLayoutPanel2.Controls[e.Index].Controls["selected1"]
```

I've tried to create a CheckBox object and get the Name property as the value and get an error stating:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The code I'm using is:

```
try
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Control checkBox = new System.Windows.Forms.Control();
    checkBox = flowLayoutPanel2.Controls[e.Index].Controls["selected1"];
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(checkBox.Name));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
}
```

I think I'm probably just trying to access the checkbox in the wrong way, as if I just try to access the panel enclosing it I can manipulate the panel with no problems.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: what method is this code in? The click event handler for the checkbox? Where is that e (from e.Index) coming from ?

Comment: It's in the event handler for a list view which displays the same data. At the moment I've got the checkboxes in the flow layout panels updating the corresponding list view checkbox but I've been struggling to do the reverse. e is the list view checkbox, e.Index is the index and as they're the same order its the same numbered panel.

Comment: Not your Q which was answered below but: the " = new" part is not needed. It creates a unused control since in the next line you reassign the variable. Also checkBox.Name is a string so Convert.ToString() is also unneeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear where `e.Index` is coming from, but I don't think it's necessary:

```
CheckBox checkBox;
if (flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.ContainsKey("selected1")) {
  checkBox = (CheckBox)flowLayoutPanel2.Controls["selected1"];
}
```

If you are interested in the value, it's probably best to use CheckBox instead of just Control.

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot more sense to do it that way. I hadn't figured out the ContainsKey function.